# In memory database with OUTER APPLY support in Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have been tasked with writing integration tests in Python. My company's application uses SQL Server. To mock the database in memory, I have been using the `sqlite3` package. However, one of the SQL Server queries I need to test uses an `OUTER APPLY` function, but this type of query is unsupported by sqlite. Changing the original query I need to test is not an option. Are there any in-memory databases I can use in Python that support MSSQL `OUTER APPLY` functions? If not, what could my other options be?

This is the general format of my query for reference:

```
"""
        SELECT ... 
        FROM ...
        LEFT JOIN ... ON ... = ...
        OUTER APPLY (...) 
        WHERE ...
"""
```

Comment: Why not develop on sql server, if that's what you have to use anyway?

Comment: I had considered that previously, but it is not an option. In-memory is necessary for my project requirements.

Comment: I don't understand how that can be, if your company's application uses SQL Server. The result of your work would have to run on sql server too, right? Good luck anyway

Comment: I don't know of any such in-memory databases that would work for you. You will have to write an equivalent query for sqlite to use for your testing - I would consider all such tests as mocks of database results, and in no way sufficient as tests of the database queries that will be used in production.